# Jboss wsconsume with non-standard ca-cert

Tags: web-services, jboss, jax-ws

So I have a webservice that I would like to generate a client for, I would like to do this for JBoss 5.1. Sounds simple but the server (and wsdl) is on secure http with a ca-cert that is not by trusted standard ca-certs. I have the public ca-cert and have created a keystore (jks) that I would like to use during generation of the client but this when run in to trouble.

The thing I would not like to add the ca-cert to javas trusted cert but I would like to use on the command line, normally not a problem, but with "wsconsume" I can find a way to do it?!

The "Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=ca_cert.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=pass" do not work as the shell script can't handle them. So what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the JVM args by setting `JAVA_OPTS` env. variable, i.e. on Linux

```
> export JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/your/.keystore"
> wsconsume.sh -k https://yoursite.net/yourws?wsdl
```

Note that the `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` is not required.